# Can I fix a DB2 Query Timeout through a configuration change alone?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, db2

Can I fix a DB2 Connection Timeout through a configuration change alone?

Note that I am running the following version of the db2 client connectivity software:

```
Y:\>db2level
DB21085I  Instance "DB2" uses "32" bits and DB2 code release "SQL08015" with
level identifier "02060106".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v8.1.5.449", "s040212", "WR21334", and FixPak
"5".
```

I noticed that when I brought up the Configuration Assistant that there seemed to be a connection-level option for setting the QueryTimeout value:

[image]
However, I wanted to change the value. Since there was no "Update" button, only an Add, I thought that I might have to Delete the setting and re-add it to modify it. however, when I went to re-add it, the QueryTimeOout setting was not in my list.

[image]

It may be that I updated a config file somewhere and this is how the asetting was first introduced. I don't remember.

1. I would like to know where I can find the location of the file
   which contains these settings.
2. This setting *is* available on another person's PC who has a newer version of the db2
       client. Will setting it to 0 on his PC override any default CommandTimeout
       setting in the program? Note that the query does not timeout on my PC, only on the other user's PC.
3. I tried to change my ConnectionString in
       the app.config file of this WinForm app to include the option
       "QueryTimeout=0"

connectionString="Database=MyServer;Server=MyHost.MyCompany.com:MyPortNumber;UID=MyuserId;PWD=MyPassword;QueryTimeout=0"

but I get the following error:

Additional information: Invalid argument

[Here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClassConnectionStringProperty.html) is the documentation on this ConnectionString setting   . What am I doing wrong?

Gets or sets the value of the QueryTimeout keyword. The QueryTimeout indicates the default number of seconds to wait for an SQL statement or XQuery expression to complete executing before attempting to cancel the execution and return control to the application. This attribute overrides the default 30 second DB2Command.CommandTimeout value.

Comment: Command Time out is not connection time out, which do you want. More to the point Connection time out is raised when you can't connect to the server, so putting it in the server would be a tad pointless...

Comment: Also your link is to the interface which implementation are you using OLEConnection ODBC ?

Comment: @Tony-The error was a timeout when querying. I'll correct the title of my post. Thanks for the reply and sorry for the misdirection.

Comment: Can't say I've ever tried putting a querytimeout in a connection string. Nor do I see a great deal of use in a default one. When I'm working with a query that's known to be slow and I can't / won't do something about that, I simply set the command timeout property after instantiating the command.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following from the db2 command line (db2cmd).

```
    db2"update cli configuration for section common using querytimeoutinterval 60"
```

Sets the time to 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should set "QueryTimeout=30" in app.config file to cancel the query after execution of 30 seconds. QueryTimeout is not a CLI Keyword and hence you can't set it as CLI Parameter using Configuration assistance or db2 command line tool. You can set it either in app.config file or db2dsdriver.cfg file or by setting statement attribute SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT.

Default value of QueryTimeoutInterval is 1 second. It will check every 1 sec that timeout has occurred or not. It is a CLI keyword and you can add it in db2cli.ini file, but it will not be effective for .NET program. .NET application does not read db2cli.ini file.